# How to improve remember password option when you have different logins for different subdirectories?

Tags: html, passwords, remember-me

Browser remember password feature is nice one but it has a problem when you do have several logins for several sections, something like:

- / - one login
- /private/  - another login
- /admin/ - another login

The problem is what you can do in order to make the browser be smarter and do proper rember/autocomplete of user/passwords for each section.

I'm mostly interested about Chrome and Firefox :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the browser will remember based on some or all of the below:

- hostname (i.e. domain.com)
- path (i.e. /admin
- name and id of input field (i.e. )

If you have three different logins and want it to remember separate passwords I'd suggest alternating among the above (e.g. change so that the name/id differs).

If you have one single login on three separate urls (that is essentially the same), I'd suggest merging to one url and form for it to remember.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Im looking for a way to modify the html forms to solve this issue. Unified login is not an option in hhis case.